# Connecting external server to Ethereum node via RPC failed "bind: cannot assign requested address"

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, rpc

I am trying to connect an external server to my Ethereum node. Considering I don't want to use `--rpcaddr 0.0.0.0` (which it works)for security reasons, I am using the following command to start geth:

```
geth console --syncmode "fast" --rpcapi personal,web3,eth --rpc --rpcaddr 95.179.179.41 --rpcport 8545
```

but I get the following error:

```
Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen tcp 95.179.179.41:8545: bind: cannot assign requested address
```

How do I whitelist an IP address to the port 8545 correctly?

Comment: I got rid of that error by using `--http.addr` instead of `--rpcaddr`, and geth starts syncing, but the external server still not able to connect.

Comment: Have you replaced each `--rpc*` with `--http.*` in your geth args, or only `--rpcaddr`?